# <select> in Symfony

Tags: symfony, twig

How do I can create a  in symfony form from the controller?

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($fupv)
   ->add('idUsuario', 'text')
   ->add('permiso', 'text')//I want a select here
   ->add('save', 'submit')
   ->getForm();
```

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow, you should have found an answer in the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#built-in-field-types).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a **choice Field Type**.
There are various options depending on how you are populating the select.

A simple example;

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($fupv)->add('gender', 'choice', array(
    'permiso' => array('a' => 'Admin', 'u' => 'User')
));
```

Have a look at [the symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices) for more examples.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the choice field type

```
->add('myField', 'choice', array(
               'choices'=> array('choice1'=>'printedvalueofchoice1','choice2'=>'printedvalueofchoice2'),
           'multiple'=> false,
           'expanded'=> false ))
```

expanded set to true will turn your select into radio options